# Dynamic options and rd-cli

Tags: rundeck

I'm using a rundeck workflow that retrieve some options, dinamically throught URL. It's a dependent option scenario.

Currently, on rundeck web GUI it works fine, I write a machine name on one option, and with this data, the next 2 options (vcenter_cluster and destination_host) get automatically selected by a URL.

Question.

¿How can I run this scenario with rd-cli?

I'm using this command line

`./rd run -j 'JOB-NAME' -p PROJECT_NAME -- -vm_name XXXXXX`

But, I got he following error

`Error: Job options were not valid: Option 'vcenter_cluster' is required. [code: api.error.job.options-invalid; APIv34] Request failed: 400 Bad Request`

Remember that vcenter_cluster is get by a remote URL value, that depends on vm_name value Here, I append the options code definition

`

- description: VM name
  label: Nombre de la VM
  name: vm_name
  required: true

  - description: Indica el cluster al que pertenece la VM. Es un parametro obtenido automaticamente
    enforced: true
    label: Cluster al que pertenece la VM
    name: vcenter_cluster
    required: true
    valuesUrl: http://localhost:8080/wssh/wssh_mini.php?o=2&value=${option.vm_name.value}
  - description: Host al que deberá migrarse la VM. Se calcula automaticamente,obteniendose el que mejor se adapta para albergar la carga de la VM
    enforced: true
    label: Host ESXi destino
    name: destination_host
    valuesUrl: http://localhost:8080/wssh/wssh_mini.php?o=1&cluster=${option.vcenter_cluster.value}
    `

NOTE that destintion_host option depends on vcenter_cluster option value retrieved by http request

How Can I call this kind of job with this options scenarios using rd-cli?

In case, that is no possible to use rd-cli, ¿any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get the remote value first, store it, and pass it to [API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html)/[RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) later. I did an example using [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/) service (only gets a dynamic UUID string).

Job definition:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='remoteopt' valuesUrl='https://httpbin.org/uuid' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${option.remoteopt}</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Example script (needs [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), first through API, later through RD CLI):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# get remote option (jq required)
value=$(curl -s -X GET "https://httpbin.org/uuid" -H  "accept: application/json" | jq -r .uuid)

# API way
curl -s --location --request POST "http://localhost:4440/api/36/job/3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267/run" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: qNcao2e75iMf1PmxYfUJaGEzuVOIW3Xz" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "{ \"argString\":\"-remoteopt $value \" }" | jq

# RD CLI way
rd run -j HelloWorld -p ProjectEXAMPLE -- -remoteopt $value
```

API way output:

```json
{
  "id": 7,
  "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/execution/7",
  "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/7",
  "status": "running",
  "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
  "executionType": "user",
  "user": "admin",
  "date-started": {
    "unixtime": 1606492098371,
    "date": "2020-11-27T15:48:18Z"
  },
  "job": {
    "id": "3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267",
    "averageDuration": 407,
    "name": "HelloWorld",
    "group": "",
    "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
    "description": "",
    "options": {
      "remoteopt": "0a2bee6e-0b1a-437b-86a2-d068a6be3b8c"
    },
    "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/job/3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267",
    "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267"
  },
  "description": "echo ${option.remoteopt}",
  "argstring": "-remoteopt 0a2bee6e-0b1a-437b-86a2-d068a6be3b8c",
  "serverUUID": "2f8f73a2-b494-4001-8244-0a35db3d9948"
}
```

RD CLI way output:

```sh
# Found matching job: 3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267 HelloWorld
# Execution started
8 running 2020-11-27T12:48:19-0300 - http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/8 job 3e768690-7124-4b97-8085-b1598ed11267 /HelloWorld
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRdXS.jpg) the result.